# how to convert string to dictionary in python

Tags: python, json, dictionary

In logs I print dictionary converted to string

Output in log:

```
  {'email': 'brian-o'connor@aaaaa.com'}
```

Then I try to convert this string back to dict.

```
print json.loads(my_str)
```

This is an error I got:

```
simplejson.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 1 (char 1)
```

How to escape this string without loosing single quote in email?

Comment: How did you print that to the log? It's not JSON, and you shouldn't expect `json.loads` to be able to read it.

Comment: have you tired `\'`?

Comment: @Wooble, agreed, it's not a json. Any solution to convert it to be a dictionary?

Comment: @Csanesz, yes, but I need to escape ' in email, all other ' should became a double quote

Comment: I suggest configuring your logging system so that it prints valid JSON instead of the output you're getting now. It's easier to tell the logging system "print string representations using double quote marks" rather than telling the decoder "try to figure out which characters are quote marks, and which ones are incidental apostrophes"

Comment: @Kevin, you're right. But for many reasons I can't do this.

Answer (score 2):

Your example is not a valid JSON as only double quotes are allowed for enclosing key-value pairs.
The valid JSON string should look like `'{"email": "brian-o\'connor@aaaaa.com"}'`

If I'd take the original string, it could be transformed to a valid format this fancy way:

```
import ast, json

s = "{'email': 'brian-o\\'connor@aaaaa.com'}"
# note nested apostrophe need to be escaped for literal parsing

valid_s = json.dumps( ast.literal_eval(s) )
# we have valid json string now '{"email": "brian-o\'connor@aaaaa.com"}'

# Now we can get python's dictionary back
d = json.loads(valid_s)  # {u'email': u"brian-o'connor@aaaaa.com"}
d['email']               # u"brian-o'connor@aaaaa.com"
```

Comment: Of course I can do this. My question is how to make that string (and any other strings of this kind) to work

Comment: Without a crystal ball or your code showed how *"In logs do you print dictionary converted to string"* is not possible to answer the question. I just guess you improperly call `__str__` or `__repr__` instead of `json.dumps`. Then you can't expect inverse `json.loads` would work.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:-

```
>>> import ast
>>> ast.literal_eval("{'email': 'brian-o\\'connor@aaaaa.com'}")
{'email': 'brian-o connor@aaaaa.com'}
```

Comment: Do you suggest me to escape ' manually? Not an option, it's part of the script

Answer (score -1):

You input do not correct.
The expection complain about it "Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 1 ".
you input : {'email': 'brian-o'connor@aaaaa.com'}. It's not fit the syntax of python.

Comment: It does fit python syntax. E.g. I can print this string. No errors

Comment: can you paster all you code (the part include the mystr define  and print and json.loads )?